# CSS Clear Float not working

Tags: html, css

Having an issue with clearing floats that I have used and I don't understand why it is not working.

I have got some information in a three column layout and I have tried clearing the floats so that I can continue adding information below,however it is not going below.

HTML

```
<div class="aboutme">
<h1>About Me</h1>
<p>
<br>
<br>
<a>My name is <strong>Richard Warner</strong> and I am a young web designer from          Birmingham, UK. I have recently graduated from Manchester Metropolitan University having studied BSc(Hons) Multimedia Computing</a>. 
</p>
</div>

<div class="skills">
<h1>Skills & Expertise</h1>
<p>
<br>
<br>
<ul id="skilllist">
<li><a>HTML & CSS</a></li>
<li><a>PHP</a></li>
<li><a>MySQL</a></li>
<li><a>Wordpress</a></li>
<li><a>Adobe Photoshop</a></li>
<li><a>Adobe Dreamweaver</a></li>
</ul>
</p>
</div>

<div class="cv">
<h1>My CV</h1>
<p>
<br>
<br>
<a>You can download my CV by clicking here</a>
</p>
</div>

</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
<div id="portfolio"><a>addsassadasd</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.aboutme {
width: 300px;
height: 210px;
border: solid 1px #000;
float: left;
}

.skills {
width: 300px;
height: 210px;
border: solid 1px #000;
float: left;
margin-left: 27px;
}

.cv {
width: 300px;
height: 210px;
float: left;
border: solid 1px #000;
margin-left: 27px;

}

#clear {

clear:both;
}
```

I have checked to make sure I have closed DIV tags and they are all closed. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have `#clear` as a class? Seeing as there's a chance you'll  want it more than once?

Comment: What do you mean? I have got a 960px wide DIV which has three 300px wide divs inside it.

Comment: Don't add height to your divs, let them get height automatically from content inside it. Or increase height, its too small

Comment: seems to work fine in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DyMpQ/
It seems like you added a </div> to much though (just above your clear div)

Comment: Just to add that "&" have to be "&amp;" in HTML to prevent parsing errors and <ul> are not allowed inside <p> according to w3C spec.

Comment: Ah yeah the </div> above the clear div was causing the issue. Thanks for your help.

@Sourabh I don't tend to give the divs height, was accidental! Thanks.

Comment: Another good practice - try to rely on css margins and paddings for vertical spacing instead of using the <br /> tag.  This way, if you ever change you mind about the space, you can fix it in the css without ever touching the HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `</div>` near the end.  What is the expected behavior?  Your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ffubr/) does seem to render just as it should.  Everything after the clearing div is below the floating elements that are above it.

```
<div id="clear"></div>
<div id="portfolio"><a>addsassadasd</a>
    This is below the floats above<br>
    Not a word of a lie
</div>
```

Comment: A lesson in writing organized documents - always tidy! Format properly, tab properly (whatever your convention), and you will save yourself time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

check this if it helps :

http://jsbin.com/ofunas/4/

CSS:

```
.aboutme {
width: 300px;
height: 310px;
border: solid 1px #000;
float: left;

}

.skills {
width: 300px;
height: 310px;
border: solid 1px #000;
float: left;
margin-left: 27px;
}

.cv {
width: 300px;
height: 310px;
float: left;
border: solid 1px #000;
margin-left: 27px;

}

#clear {
display:block;
clear:both;
}
.div4 {
width: 300px;
height: 310px;
border: solid 1px #000;
float: left;
margin-top:20px;
}
```